# How to access a variable outside a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I have written the following code snippet to read the total number of lines present in a file. But I cannot access the counter's value outside of the readstream. When I print constraints and goals at the end it gives me 0. The expected outcome should be the total number of goals and constraints. Please help me with this.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const folder = './project/';
var actors = 0;
goals = 0;
constraints=0;
fs.readdirSync(folder).forEach(file => {
    actors = actors+1;
    fs.readdirSync(folder+file).forEach(f=>{
        var path = folder+file+'/'+f;
        var k = 0;
        var r1 = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(path),
            output: process.stdout,
            terminal:false
        });
        r1.on('line',(line)=>{
            k++;
        });
        r1.on('close',()=>{
             if(f==='Constraints.txt'){
                 constraints=constraints+k;
            
             }
             else{
                 goals=goals+k;
            
              }
        
          })
     });

 });

console.log(actors);
console.log(constraints);
console.log(goals);
```

Comment: that's because your code is async: the readline interface has not yet run when you print the results.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion that would solve my problem specifically mentioned in the code?